# Can not add new files to existing drives after elementary OS Juno install

Tags: release-juno, hardware, install

I recently replaced Window 7 Pro with elementary OS Juno for my HTPC. I have 3 drives that I'm using. Drive 1. is Main drive for elementary OS Juno. Drive 2. For Movies and Music. Drive 3 is for more Movies and Music. I can not transfer(copy/paste) new movies or music files to drives 2 or 3. Either the Paste option is grey out or it gives me an error of drive is read only.
Do I need to reformat drives 2 and 3 under elementary OS Juno in order for me to copy/paste new files? Or is there a way around this without losing all my data?

Thank you
New elementary OS User

Comment: Exactly the same reason why i am here, i came to check this thread if there's an answer